# Post rate-limiting without explanation

Tags: support, bug

This post is for a fellow user, @Christopher, who cannot post a question about this issue because of this issue :P

Essentially, he has not posted anything onto Puzzling.SE in the past while (last and only post on Mar 31), but when he tried posting something earlier today, it said "you may only post every 40 minutes". An inspection of his profile does not offer any clues, so does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Thanks for posting for me XD

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/hUcPp

Comment: Image of me trying to post ^^

Comment: @Chris have you posted a question anywhere else in the past hour?

Answer (score 3):

@Christoper posted [this question](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2745/may-i-use-the-logo-here-on-the-top-bar-with-citation) less than 40 minutes ago. As Puzzling is not a site where you have 200 reputation, you are rate limited.

Comment: oh that makes sense, thanks

Comment: The good news is, it's been 40 minutes now, so he can ask his question :)

Comment: Wait that makes no sense. That is on a different SE

Comment: @Christoper - yep. I've encountered this as well, even with a diamond on the network :/

Comment: @Mithrandir This may be a bigger bug

Comment: @Christoper - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/286036/lets-re-evaluate-the-question-timer

Comment: [Users with < 125 rep, 40 minutes since their last question anywhere on the network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide)

Comment: @Martin - ah, thanks. Didn't remember the exact number :)